# Global supremum vs trajectory supremum in dynamical system

Tags: analysis, dynamical-systems

I have a very basic question. Suppose I have a dynamical system $x_{t+1}=f(x_t)$ where $f$ is a nice function, $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$. I am trying to connect $\sup_{x\in[0,1]}f(x)$ with $\sup_{t\geq0} f(x_t)$. Obviously the former is larger. However, I am interested to know when these two are equal. I am trying to guess some properties of $f$ that might be useful for me.

One simple idea is that the $x_t$ must hover infinitely often around the maximum $x^*$ where $x^*=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}f(x)$. Is this enough? Are there any references or useful criteria on $f$ so that this can be achieved?